# Translate a string with cm to an integer with mm

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a string which contains `10.2`, that I want to convert to an integer `102`. I thought I'd do

```
int(float('10.2')*10)
```

but then all kind of floating point error alarm bells start ringing.

Is there another (Pythonic) way to convert the string `'10.2'` to the integer `102` ?

Comment: works for me (on 2.7 and 3.5). Can you post the specific error/warning you are getting?

Comment: @bunji I am not getting an error. This will in fact work, but we all know that not all decimal values can precisely be represented by a float.

Comment: Is your multiple always a power of ten?

Comment: I'm just a little confused as to why you're worried about precision when you're converting to an integer as a final step. For example if your string was `'10.21'` then you'll lose the precision after the decimal during the conversion to integer step, not the conversion to float step.

Comment: @bunji but what if `9.3` becomes `9.2999999999999999929` as float, I multiply getting `92.999999999999929` and make it an integer, I get `92` and not `93`.

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, I just want to convert a string that has centimeter into millimeter in integer.

Comment: Ok thank you. That example clarifies your question for me.

Comment: `int(round(float('10.2') * 10, 0))`

Comment: Have I missed the point? `int(10*Decimal('10.2'))`

Comment: @BillBell my Python says no: `name 'Decimal' is not defined`

Comment: 'New' in Python 2.4. Use `from decimal import *`.